# How to extend jQuery plugins?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to create a jQuery plugin to wrap a chart component. It will have functions like addLineSerie or addBarsSerie. Then I want to create other plugins that extend this one to add new functionality or overwrite what's needed but still be able to call the original plugin functions.

I started with the approach below. It kind of works but, as I realized later, I can't call the original "parent" implementation (if I create an instance of myB, I can't call myA.goA2).

```
(function($){
    $.fn.myA = function(settings) {
        this.goA = function() {alert("goA: "+settings);};
        this.goA2 = function() {alert("goA2: "+settings);};
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);

(function($){
    $.fn.myB = function(settings) {
        this.myA(settings);
        this.goA2 = function() {alert("goA2B: "+settings);};
        this.goB = function() {alert("goB: "+settings);};
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

So I have 2 questions:

1. Is this approach right or I should be doing this in a different way?
2. How do make the "parent" and the "child" be the same instance a yet get to call the "parent's" implementation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems about right, but to accomplish cross-plugin behavior can't you just do this:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myA = function(settings) {
        this.goA = function() {
            alert("goA: " + settings);
        };
        this.goA2 = function() {
            alert("goA2: " + settings);
        };
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);

(function($) {
    $.fn.myB = function(settings) {
        this.myA = $.fn.myA(settings);
        this.goA2fromA = function() {
            this.myA.goA2();
        };
        this.goA2 = function() {
            alert("goA2B: " + settings);
        };
        this.goB = function() {
            alert("goB: " + settings);
        };
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
    var a = $('#one').myA({});
    var b = $('#one').myB({});
    a.goA2();
    b.goA2fromA();
});
```

EDIT: fixed the call to myA and added the call that one would make.  Check out the working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/PqQgs/4/

Comment: It's still calling the child implementation, isn't it?

Comment: oops, fixed, I was instantiating myA incorrectly (trying to do this during meetings was a bad idea :)

Comment: It works. If I accept the answer, can we still post comments? Because I'm not sure I get it. b can call the NOT overriden methods and yet even if I declare local public variables on myA there's no conflict between variables a and b. Is this because variable b has its own instances of both plugins myA and myB? If you could explain a little what is going behind the scenes it would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Of course you can still comment after accepting.  I think you're making it a little too complicated.  a is assigned an instance of the myA plugin for the #one div.  b is assigned an instance of the myB plugin for the same div.  The myB plugin also keeps an internal instance of the myA plugin.  so myB can call myA methods.  It's not inheritance, it's just a reference to an object of "type" myA.  I put that in quotes because all this object oriented stuff is just simulated in JS.  Good read: http://www.klauskomenda.com/code/javascript-programming-patterns/

Comment: Yes. But you can directly call b.goA(); How is that posible if the reference from myB to myA is just internal? (and I assume that the instance that gets called is not the one created for var a although it is the same div, because I tried to use some local public variables and there was no value overriding)

Comment: b.goA2 just calls myB's version of goA2, it has nothing to do with myA's goA2.  Using myB's internal myA instance, however, you can get to myA's goA2.

Comment: No, I wasn't refering to goA2, you can call **goA** --> b.goA();

Comment: Oh I see what's confusing.  You're looking at just the function call.  Look where it comes from: the `$(...).myA()` and `$(...).myB()` functions return totally different objects.  So `$(...).myA().goA()` is totally different from `$(...).myB().goA()`.  I think you're thinking it's `$(...).goA()` and forgetting about the instantiation of the plugin done with `myB()` and `myA()`.

Comment: Mmm... I see that, but that's not exactly my question. Thanks for your patience and effort, I really appreciate it. Feel free to stop answering when you want. Let me put it this way: how does it come that I can do both of these: `$('#one').myB({}).goA();` and `$('#one').myB({}).myA.goA();` Initially, I would have thought that the second one would work, but not the first one. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: By debugging I see that goA is in the __proto__ of the object, but I have no idea how it got there. I suppose it has something to do with how jQuery creates the plugins...

Comment: `this.goA2 = function()` does just that.

Comment: myB doesn't have a goA method.  If you're still not getting this you need to clear your mind and read through it again.  You've got all the info you need right here.

Comment: That's my point. I think it shouldn't have a `goA` method. But if call it (from b or myB), it works! You can try it yourself by adding `b.goA();` or `$('#one').myB({}).goA();` to your fiddle.